# Send Email with SP.ClientContent

Tags: 2010, client-object-model

Is it possible to send email using SP.ClientContext. Im aware of the limitations of send email in Javascript, but my understanding is that this calls the back end. All i see related to CSOM is c# code.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you tried and what is not working? Are you trying to sent email using JavaScript Object Model?

Comment: Have you looked at this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/203b5fe4-18c4-414f-902d-ca369781e1de/send-email-using-csom?forum=appsforsharepoint

Comment: you tag 2010, but I suppose you are talking about 2013.

Comment: No im talking about 2010

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send an email using CSOM (js) you can use this:

```
function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {

    var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;

    var urlTemplate = siteurl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
                'From': from,
                'To': { 'results': [to] },
                'Body': body,
                'Subject': subject
            }
        }
      ),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
           alert("Eposten ble sendt");
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.responseText);
            debugger;
        }
    });
}
```

Just note that the recipient is limited to a valid SharePoint user for security reasons.

[Sending Email with SharePoint and JQuery](http://geekswithblogs.net/ThorvaldBoe/archive/2014/07/03/sending-email-with-sharepoint-and-jquery.aspx)

[technet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30058.how-to-send-email-in-sharepoint-provider-hosted-apps.aspx)

Comment: I believe this only applies to 2010

Comment: to 2013 u meant?

Comment: Yes, I meant it applied to 2013. Gave up and used c#

Comment: for 2010 take a look of this (js + workflow): http://spjsblog.com/2010/06/16/send-email-with-javascript-with-the-help-of-a-workflow-in-a-dedicated-send-email-list/

Comment: thanks for the link. I also have the complication of allowing it for anonymous users, and workflows wont fire if the item is created anonymously (unless you make a farm wide change via powershell)

Comment: How can send to multiple email at one time